# SpringRoo @RooWebScaffold, generate source code

Tags: spring, spring-roo, scaffolding

I am partly following quickstart tutorial at http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/#quick-start.

I created an entity class and generated MVC using `web mvc all --package ~.web` command.

Question I have is that my controller class has scaffolding done using `@RooWebScaffold`, how do I generate the code for it? Is there a command synonymous to Grails `generate all`. In grails this command would actually generate actions called `update, edit, delete, insert etc` with full code which can be edited.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Roo generates code in aspects. These aspects are then integrated into the application code using the ajc compiler.

That is why you do not see any code in the controller. In order to see the code in the controller you need to use the Push-In refactoring that is provided by both Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEs.

Keep in my that if you push-in the aspects into the application code, you will no longer be able to add new code to that controller with Roo.

Comment: Thanks a lot, is there a way to push in all the methods? I am right clicking on the *.aj file and then cliking on AspectJ Refactorying -> Push in. This only pushes the first method! By the way i am using eclipse

Comment: I remember when I was doing it, I would just right click on the aj files in the project explorer and then in the menu I would just select push in. (It has been a while since I used it, so my memory on what exactly you need to do might be a little fuzzy :))

Answer (score 2):

The code generated by ROO is based on AspectJ.

If you want "pure Java code" in order to adapt it after generation 
you should try Telosys Tools http://tools.telosys.org

The tutorial for Spring MVC / JPA is here : https://sites.google.com/site/telosystutorial/